# how to assign vector to object by reference?

Tags: c++, oop, pass-by-reference

My try:

```
class myClass {
  std::vector<int> myVector;
 public:
  myClass(std::vector<int> &v) {
    this->myVector = v;
  }
  void doSomething() {
    for (int &num : this->myVector) {
      num += 100;
    }
  }
};
```

in main():

```
vector<int> myVect = {1,2,3,4};
myClass myClassInst(myVect);
myClassInst.doSomething();
```

but then checking:

```
for (int i : myVect) {
  printf("%i\n", i);
}
```

Makes no change to the original vector.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, vector should be changed through object of course. Last loop is for checking.

Comment: You pass the vector by reference to the constructor, but the constructor copies the contents of the passed vector to the data member `myVector`. That is, `myClassInst.myVector` and `myVect` are unrelated.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to store a reference to another object in your class, you need to use something which actually refers to the original object. References look like the obvious choice but they are poor data members! Instead, you want to use a pointer:

```
class myClass {
    std::vector<int>* myVector;
public:
    myClass(std::vector<int>& vector): myVector(&myVector) {}
    void doSomething() {
        for (auto& num: *myVector) {
            num += 100;
        }
    }
};
```